Quant Probability Question -- Exponential Distribution
Consider the following problem from QuantQuestions.io:
Two machines independently manufacture Bakugan and Beyblade toys. The time it takes each machine to produce a toy is Exp(1) distributed. The manufacturing time is independent of all other toys. Assume there is no delay between when a machine produces a toy to when it starts the next toy. Find the probability that the third Bakugan is manufactured before the second Beyblade.
In the solution, they write that "the key to this question is the following realization: When a toy is produced at all, it is equally likely to be a Bakugan or a Beyblade. The reason is because of the memorylessness property and the fact that they have equal rates of production."
I agree with the claim that when a toy is produced at all, it is equally likely to be either a Bakugan or Beyblade. However, the reason to this is specific to the fact that they each have identical exponential distributions -- that is, if they had identical probability distributions for their productions, but the distributions were not exponential, then this claim would not be true. For example, consider the uniform distribution between $[0,T]$ and where it is zero everywhere else. Then, at any given instant it would not be true that each toy is equally likely to be produced. Is my reasoning correct? Any help is appreciated!

The exponential distribution is memoryless: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Memorylessness_property_of_exponential_random_variable. The uniform distribution is not memoryless.
